# Are states (always) a fundamental notion in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

When dealing with quantum mechanics one usually postulates states* as fundamental notions. They form basis of the Hilbert space(H) and are used to compute expected values of observables which we "measure" in the lab.

Beyond the all mighty notion of Hilbert spaces I'd like to point some other ideas. First, the space of operators supported by H. Mathematicians often prefer to treat QM in the frame of operators, not states(as in C* algebras etc) but I don't think they are actually concerned with what one actually measures in the lab. Yet this shows that we can learn some formal structure of QM from the operator algebra itself.

At the other hand, pure states are unrealistic. Hard to prepare in the lab, as much as a good deal of the whole Hilbert space so that in practice the real world contain very few of the possibilities given by H. Ideas such as quantum state tomography show that in certain cases one can reconstruct states from measurements, placing measurements in a more fundamental place in some sense.

In general I don't feel we can get rid of states. What I want to understand is: **in which contexts can we drop the notion of state**.

I shall also give a little more background on such question. I'm interested in quantifying quantum information in certain QM systems. The line between genuinely quantum information and classical  is blurred. Entanglement seems to be a notion tied to states. One can talk about discord which is still calculated by means of states ($\rho$). Non-commutativity also gives rise to observable's correlations picking up when evolved in Heisenberg picture, but non-commutativity is not only quantum! Moreover, one can talk about entropy of a channel by maximizing von Neumman's entropy over all states and thus getting rid of them (cf. [Entropy of a quantum channel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.06980)).

**At the end of the day I want to ask/open a discussion on whether we can or cannot grasp some genuinely quantum features without resorting to states.**

*By states here I mean either pure or mixed.

Comment: *"At the end of the day I want to ask/open a discussion"* - [Stackexchange isn't a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110)

Comment: Ok! Never mind the open discussion part. I put it there because I don't know if the question is open of not. Examples and/or answers are welcome.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you putting forward quantum *state* tomography as an example of a case in which you can "drop the notion of state"? How can you conceive reconstructing a state without the notion of state? If not, I don't understand what is *a* context in which you can drop the notion of state. Also, I do not understand how the bit about "pure states are unrealistic" is related to the rest.

Comment: or are you maybe referring to "dropping the notion of state" at a more formal level? Like, whether one can do QM without using kets or DMs?

Comment: By that comment on tomography what I meant was that if one can reconstruct very well the ensembles by making measurements states could be looked as a not so fundamental structure.

At a more formal level, as I mentioned, I don't think one can drop the notion of states besides the C* algebra approach which is much more mathematically oriented.  You can take "drop the notion of state" as obtaining results which are valid to any state, so that one can exploit in practical application without worrying about preparing a very special state.

Comment: e.g.: Building up a quantum communication quality quantifier which characterize a system for any input state. Would this work?